# Using Recursion to Reverse a String

Tags: java, string, recursion, reverse

I am trying to reverse a String word by word using recursion. (Ex: "Hello my friend" is reversed to "friend my Hello") This is the code I have attempted to write for this method. I have tried multiple similar variations but the output is only ever the first or last word of the String. I believe the part that is "broken" is the first if statement, but I am not quite sure.

```
public static String reverse (String words) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(words);
   String backwards = "";

   if (sc.hasNext()) {
     String currentWord = sc.next();
     reverse(sc.nextLine());
     backwards = backwards + " " + currentWord;
   } //end if
   else {
     backwards = words;
   } //end else

   return backwards;
 }
```

I am aware that a few similar questions exist, but their answers have not seemed to help me understand my mistake(s).

Thanks!

Comment: You're not saving the result of your recursive call.

Comment: I'm going to give that a look, thanks! @JornVernee

Comment: I haven't worked much with StringBuilder, I'll look into it! @OusmaneDiaw

Comment: @Gabbie i can provide you a solution with stringbuilder if you want.

Comment: @OusmaneDiaw Sure! I'd appreciate it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a `Scanner`, you can make use of an overload of `String.split` to split `words` around the first space:

```
public static String reverse(String words) {
    String[] wordArr = words.split(" ", 2); // split into a maximum of 2 Strings

    if (wordArr.length > 1) { // If there is more than 1 word
        // return the first word (wordArr[0]),
        // behind the reverse of the rest of the String (wordArr[1])
        return reverse(wordArr[1]) + " " + wordArr[0];
    }

    return wordArr[0]; // else, just return the one word
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem and was simple and well explained, thanks!! :)

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't call `nextLine()` because your input is all on one line. Your logic is much clearer if you begin by creating a simple helper method, it should take an array of `words` and a position; from there you can recursively build your desired output with something like

```
private static String reverse(String[] words, int p) {
    if (p + 1 < words.length) {
        return reverse(words, p + 1) + " " + words[p];
    } else if (p < words.length) {
        return words[p];
    }
    return "";
}
```

Then your `public` method is easy to implement, just `split` the original input on white space and call `reverse` starting at `0` (remembering to `return` the result). Like,

```
public static String reverse(String words) {
    return reverse(words.split("\\s+"), 0);
}
```

And then, I tested it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(reverse("Hello my friend"));
}
```

Which outputs (as requested)

```
friend my Hello
```

*Alternatively*, you could make that helper take your `Scanner` instead like

```
private static String reverse(Scanner sc) {
    if (sc.hasNext()) {
        String currentWord = sc.next();
        if (sc.hasNext()) {
            return reverse(sc) + " " + currentWord;
        }
        return currentWord;
    }
    return "";
}
```

And then your public method is

```
public static String reverse(String words) {
    return reverse(new Scanner(words));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String reverseSentence(String sentence) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int firstSpace = sentence.indexOf(' ');
    if (firstSpace == -1) {
        return sb.append(sentence.strip()).append(" ").toString();
    }
    String secondPart = sentence.substring(firstSpace + 1); 
    String firstPart = sentence.substring(0, firstSpace);//similar to merger sort 
    return sb.append(reverseSentence(secondPart)).append(reverseSentence(firstPart)).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you could use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of Scanner class.

This example sends the same words, splits them by spaces each time you enter the method and you send the index of the word to be added in the next iteration.

For example:

```
public class RecursiveReverse {

    static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String stringToReverse = "Hello my friend!";
        System.out.println(reverse(stringToReverse, stringToReverse.split(" ").length - 1));
    }

    public static String reverse(String words, int i) {
        if (i >= 0) { //If the index of the words is greater or equals the first word
            sb.append(words.split(" ")[i]); //We split it and append it to our StringBuilder
            sb.append(" "); //We append a space
            reverse(words, --i); //We do this again
        }
        return sb.toString(); //When the above condition doesn't match we return the StringBuilder object as a String (which contains the words reversed)
    }
}
```

Which produces this output:

```
friend! my Hello
```

A better method would be passing a String array as parameter so you split only once (when sending the words as an array to the method) the String.

```
public class RecursiveReverse {

    static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String stringToReverse = "Hello my friend!";
        String words[] = stringToReverse.split(" ");
        System.out.println(reverse(words, words.length - 1));
    }

    public static String reverse(String words[], int i) {
        if (i >= 0) {
            sb.append(words[i]);
            sb.append(" ");
            reverse(words, --i);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You throw away the recursion results:

```
 reverse(sc.nextLine());
 backwards = backwards + " " + currentWord;
```

Instead, use this:

```
 backwards = reverse(sc.nextLine());
 backwards = backwards + " " + currentWord;
```

Better yet:

```
 backwards = reverse(sc.nextLine()) + " " + currentWord;
```

Comment: I have just tried this suggestion and I am getting a NoSuchElementException, any idea why?

Comment: I'll look at it if you can post the problem with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Your current code is insufficient to execute to the problem point.

Comment: I think I got it.  You're looking for the next line, instead of scanning the remainder of the current line.  REPAIR: as others have suggested, dump the Scanner altogether and just deal with string packages.  Find the next space, divide into two sub-strings at that point, and recur on the remainder of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Do you must use recursion? You can do that without it.

```java
public static String reverse(String words) {
    String[] list = words.split(" ");
    Collections.reverse(list);
    String reversed = String.join(" ", list);
    return reversed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I must use recursion :)

Answer (score 0):

You must keep  hold of the extracted words between calls in an accumulator. Here is an example.

```
public static String reverse(String words, String acc){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(words);

    if(!sc.hasNext()){
        return acc;
    }

    return reverse(sc.nextLine(), acc) + " " + sc.next();
}
```

You would call it like this.

```
reverse("Hello my friend", "");
```

It's not the most efficient implementation in the world, but yeah... It must work!

If you want a more efficient one, use a `StringBuilder` as the accumulator.